# Fusuma/Xdotool Config file not working 20.04

Tags: 20.04

i have write config file in ~/.config/fusuma/config.yml

this is the config file

```
swipe:
3:
left:
  command: "xdotool key Alt+Right" # History forward 
right:
  command: "xdotool key Alt+Left" # History back
up:
  command: "xdotool key Super" # Activity
down:
  command: "xdotool key Super" # Activity
4:
left:
  command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Down" # Switch to next workspace
right:
  command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Up" # Switch to previous workspace
up:
  command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Down" # Switch to next workspace
down:
  command: "xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+Up" # Switch to previous workspace
pinch:
in:
  command: "xdotool keydown Ctrl click 4 keyup Ctrl" # Zoom in
out:
  command: "xdotool keydown Ctrl click 5 keyup Ctrl" # Zoom out
```

and this is the output in terminal [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIdwP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check that fusuma loads your config file correctly.
Please paste output of `$ fusuma --version`